# Lost my Home CSM home page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a Sahara theme installed and wanted to change the browser tab name to my site name. It was called as per theme "Sahara Home Page".

I changed the title but I thought it was OK to change the URL key as well. Wrong! 
Now I don't see my feature products and other modules which are part of the theme. It now says "No Home CMS page configured or found".

Now I don't recall the set url key and I have no idea where to find it. 
The fields in the picture are what I believe it was as default however I don't see it restored. Even when I change the title it now stays with my shop name even after re-index, cache re-flush etc. I'm such a Rookie! but hope you can help me. ;-) [screen shot of CMS page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Np0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have selected the homepage in the `System > Configuration > Web` tab as well. The name and URL shouldn't make a difference to call the homepage from the base url

[image]